# char array initialization and destructor

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

First of all, I was not using C++ for a lot time and it is possible that this question is very easy and it does not deserve to be posted here. Anyway, I did not found any solution here or in other source.
My problem consists in following. Let's assume we have class `A`:

```
Class A
{
    char* string;
public:
    char*& getString(){ return string; }
    ~A() 
    { 
        if (string)
            delete[] string; 
    }
};
```

I cannot modify this class(it is just a sample of the real class).
I want to set field `string` to a value:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.getString() = new char[3];
    a.getString() = "Hi\0";
    return 0;
}
```

This code cause Debug Assertion Fail when destructor `~A()` is called. What I'm doing wrong here?
I really will appreciate any suggestion about what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
It seems, that assignment operator here is important. Actually, I'm doing such an assignment:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    char name[256];
    std::cin.getline(name, 256);

    a.getString() = new char[strlen(name)];
    //actual version
    strcpy_s(a.getString(), strlen(name), name);
    //a.getString() = "Hi\0";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to `delete` a statically allocated string (all string literals are statically allocated). Prefer std::string and delete your destructor (std::string uses RAII and will handle its resources automatically).

Comment: Assignment doesn't behave differently based on the current value. It will always assign the new value and overwrite the old one.

Comment: Your code boils down to `delete[] "Hi";`. You are trying to `delete` a pointer that was not allocated with `new`. You are also leaking previous allocation.

Comment: @Kevin Also, it's worth mentioning that `new char[3]` successfully leaked.

Comment: @Kevin thank you for reply, but I did not write class A and I cannot modify it at all.

Comment: @Dan sure, it is the best solution here, if I could do it.

Comment: If you have to use C-strings, then you'll have to make sure it's dynamically allocated. Use `strncpy` or some other method to copy the contents of the string (assigning it doesn't make a copy, because it's a pointer).

Comment: @Kevin Really, I forget about the difference between dynamically allocated strings and "string". I edited my question. Assignment is done using strcpy_s

Comment: Please don't show imaginary versions of code, the actual version is the only one that is needed.

Comment: There is no keyword `Class` in C++. And also no function `strcpy_s` in the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

> This code cause Debug Assertion Fail when destructor ~A() is called. What I'm doing wrong here?
>
> ```
> a.getString() = "Hi\0";
> ```

After this line, `a.string` points to a string literal. The destructor will then call `delete[]` on the pointer. Deleting a string literal has undefined behaviour. Also, the previously allocated dynamic array is leaked, since the pointer was overwritten.

The solution is to remove the quoted line.